# In ASP.NET MVC: All possible ways to call Controller Action Method from a Razor View

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know this is a pretty basic question over here.

But could you tell me ***all possible options*** available to,
  
call a ***Control Action Method [generally any server side routine] from a Razor View*** and, 
  
in what ***scenarios each are best applicable*** to be used in.

Thanks.

Comment: Check This: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Multiple-ways-to-call-Controller-Action-Method-from-a-Razor-View

Answer (score 97, accepted):

**Method 1 :** Using jQuery Ajax Get call (**partial page update**).

Suitable for when you need to retrieve jSon data from database.

**Controller's Action Method**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Foo(string id)
{
    var person = Something.GetPersonByID(id);
    return Json(person, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Jquery GET**

```
function getPerson(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Foo", "SomeController")',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        // we set cache: false because GET requests are often cached by browsers
        // IE is particularly aggressive in that respect
        cache: false,
        data: { id: id },
        success: function(person) {
            $('#FirstName').val(person.FirstName);
            $('#LastName').val(person.LastName);
        }
    });
}
```

**Person class**

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Method 2 :** Using jQuery Ajax Post call (**partial page update**).

Suitable for when you need to do partial page post data into database.

Post method is also same like above just replace  `[HttpPost]` on Action method and type as `post` for jquery method.

For more information check [**Posting JSON Data to MVC Controllers Here**](http://lozanotek.com/blog/archive/2010/04/16/posting_json_data_to_mvc_controllers.aspx)

**Method 3 :** As a Form post scenario (**full page update**).

Suitable for when you need to save or update data into database.

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveData","ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{        
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => m.Text)
    
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

**Action Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveData(FormCollection form)
    {
        // Get movie to update
        return View();
   }
```

**Method 4 :** As a Form Get scenario (**full page update**).

Suitable for when you need to Get data from database

Get method also same like above just replace  `[HttpGet]` on Action method and `FormMethod.Get` for View's form method.

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Thanks Sampath. Could you illustrate Method 2 and 4 with a sample code block. Thanks again!

Comment: Looking at it closely all 4 methods have its own differences. Would it be too much trouble if you can give a code block for each method.

Comment: Thanks Sampath. This really helped. And I think this idea would be a fine addition to your blog. Thanks again. Cheers!

Comment: @dan Glad to hear that it helped.Yes I will definetely consider to add this kind of summery thing with more details to my blog.Thanks for idea.Do Keep in touch.

Comment: Hi i tried the Method 1 to fetch the data from the controller using  jQuery Ajax Get call in MVC3 but the data in JSON format is displayed on the screen,it's not going to ajax call it seems.

Comment: @ravithejag It's better if you can start a new question with your code snippet. Then you'll have a solution.