# How to call method of a controller from View without using ajax in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing MVC application.

I am in situation that, I want to call the method of controller from View.

I don't want to use the Submit button (If I use it goes to create method.)  either I dont want to use ajax ....

I want to know that what are ways to call the method of controller from view... 
Other than submitting form process or other than ajax call.

Ex. I have a form in which user fills all the data and save it... After submit button it saves the data in DB and Saved data displayed. Now, After saving I want to transfer/pass that data from that view to another view... but I cant find appropriate method for it.

Please check image below...

I have this view after saving...now when I click on 'Click Here' Link , I want to pass the same data to another view to show the preview... some other format... 
So I am stuck on how to pass the same data ? I cant use submit as it already saved... I cant use ajax as its not partial stuff... I want to pass the entire to to another view...

[image]

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049817/in-asp-net-mvc-all-possible-ways-to-call-controller-action-method-from-a-razor

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I dont want to use Submit button or ajax...

Comment: If you have checked link you would have got that those are the only available methods to call controller action. So answer to ur question will be NO!

Comment: Well, I have situation like I want to to transfer the data from one view to another... so none of its method can apply

Comment: Every method given can satisfy your requirement!!. Methods would be of no use if it cant transfer data from view to controller. please depict your scenario

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49862/discussion-between-user1650894-and-nitin-varpe)

Comment: @user1650894 - you have some pre-conceived notions which are incorrect, and therefore you refuse to accept any answers because they contradict what you believe to be true.  Unfortunately, you have wrong information.  You are asking for an impossible solution to a problem when you have rejected any possible other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the order saved in a database on the server, you would typically pass through the ID, rather than the "entire data" to the controller method, and reload the data from the DB in order to render the other view. Is this what you're after?

View code:

```
...sent successfully. @Html.ActionLink("Click Here", "Status", new { id = Model.Id }) to check status
```

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult Status(int id) 
{
     var order = Repository.Get<Order>(id);
     return View(order);
}
```