# Showing timer from c# on html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net

Hello I am trying to implement a timer in c sharp that counts seconds and display it on my html page. But when i pass the variable to javascript it is always 0. I have searched everywhere for an answer.

This is my code so far:

The timer object:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Timers;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Class1
/// </summary>
public class TimerEu
{

    private Timer t;
    private int time;

    public TimerEu()
    {
        this.t = new Timer(1000);
        this.time = 0;

        t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(RunEvent);
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void RunEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.time++;
        Console.WriteLine(time);
    }
    public int getTime()
    {
        return this.time;
    }
}
```

aspx.cs page:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public String[] var=new String[10];
    public TimerEu time;
    public int  testint;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        time = new TimerEu();
        testint = 0;

        Console.Write("hello"+time.getTime());
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            var[i] =Operations.test.convertString();
    }

    public void plus()
    {
        this.testint++;   
    }
}
```

and the html/javascript part:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <p id="demo" runat="server"></p>

        <script>
            var now=0;

            var x= setInterval(function () {
            //now++;

            now = <%=time.getTime()%>
        //    now =<%=testint%>
         //   <%plus();%>

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = now;
    },1000)
</script>
```

The problem is that the javascript dosen't seem to call the getTime function every sec, instead it only gets 0 as output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? why do you need a server side timer? could you use a client side timer to execute methods server side instead? at the moment you effectively have two timers running.

Comment: ASP is Active Server Page, it is server side code that only runs on a postback ie page load , there  is no way it can inform java of the timer change, if you move it onto a service call you can use AJAX to call it from java but then you can do the exact same thing in pure java

Comment: the code inside `<% %>` will only get generated when the page loads and not for each iteration of the timer. If you wish to inspect the `value` of the server variable then you need to create a `webapi controller` that you call from your `javascript` but is this REALY what you want??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling ASP.NET Code Behind function from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521352/calling-asp-net-code-behind-function-from-javascript)

Comment: I know I can do it in pure javascript, but that is not my intention, the timer in c# represents a data change on the server side that the page has to detect.

Comment: @SteveDrake yes! I want to be able to call the function after the page loads

Comment: @Sergiu I would post a dif Q, or maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049817/in-asp-net-mvc-all-possible-ways-to-call-controller-action-method-from-a-razor

Comment: if you wish to enter the new world of building fancy websites, I would look into creating Single Page App my personal choice is Angular (not  angularjs but Angular) but that's my choice which ofc is subjective.  https://angular.io/

Comment: You won't be able to do what you want. As long as you want to do it in C# you will have to make an ajax call to get the result of your C# function. 
Your server is not able to send notifications to the client in webApps... At least i don't know either how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand important thing. This statement `<%=time.getTime()%>` is executed only once on the server side before rendered html page is sent to the browser. When it's executed, it will be replaced with `0` (the result of method call).

Browser will see only `now = 0` and in this case, javascript code doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var before_loadtime = new Date().getTime();
     window.onload = Pageloadtime;
     function Pageloadtime() {
         var aftr_loadtime = new Date().getTime();
         // Time calculating in seconds
         pgloadtime = (aftr_loadtime - before_loadtime) / 1000
         document.getElementById("loadtime").innerHTML = "Pgae load time is <font color='red'><b>" + pgloadtime + "</b></font> Seconds";
     }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3 style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-size: large; color: #3333CC">Page load time in JavaScript</h3>
<div>
<span id="loadtime"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: code only answer are not good answers, add a paragraph or 2 to explain how you fixed the issue and why the issue happened in the first place

Comment: it is necessary?

Comment: necessary no, good practice Yes, way of avoiding down votes and moderation definitely

Comment: I don't want to time the loading time, I want to display the data change in the c # code on the page, the timer is just the easiest way i can simiulate a data change.

Comment: mike I am new here so guide me how to give answer, my answer is correct but u r says about votes i can not understand properly.